# Count number of entries in a list when the list has one entry

Tags: python, list

After a lot of searching and trying stuff out I haven't been able to find an answer. My problem is I want to count the number of entries in a list but my list is "dynamic" so it can contain either a lot of entries or only one. The problen is the `len()` function does not return `1` when there is only one entry in the list, it returns the number of characters. When the number of entries is above `1` `len()` works fine. But I need it to return `1` not the length of the string in the list. How can I acomplish this?

So it does something like this:

```
List = ('abcdefg',)
len(List) # returns 7 instead of 1
```

but this works fine:

```
List = ('abcdefg','aqwedfd','foobar')
len(List) # returns 3
```

Comment: That's not a list. It's a string in parenthesis; the second one is a tuple. A one item tuple is written with a comma: `(1,)`

Comment: Your first example is not a list. ``type(('abc'))`` returns ``str``. Your first list should be defined as ``l = ['abcdefg']``, ``t = ('abcdefg', )`` for a tuple.

Comment: Editing the question makes this no longer a question.

Comment: The edit made the first statement about `len()` incorrect. No clue if the real program with this "dynamic" list actually does produce different types.

Comment: Although my example here was indeed wrong the problem in my code was I did first define it as an list but when it was passed on to another method I converted it to a string. It's so stupid I did not notice this. But many thanks for your replies and making me realise my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python makes lists with `[]`

```
>>> my_list = ['abcdefg']
>>> len(my_list)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of elements in a list use `len()`. You have probably accidentally counted something that is not a list e.g. a string.